# How to embed two views into a block

Tags: views, 6, blocks

I have two views that are block displays.  I'm trying to embed these views in a block.  When I include the block nothing is displayed.  If i add "test" to $block['content'] it displays test in the block body.

Here is my code ($gid is an organic group id as an argument to the block):

```
  case 5: // Create Mugshot block
    $viewName = 'display_most_wanted';
    $display_id1 = 'block_1';
    $args = array($gid);
    $wanted = views_embed_view($viewName, $display_id1, $args);

    $display_id2 = 'block_2';
    $convicted = views_embed_view($viewName, $display_id2, $args);

    $block['subject'] = 'CWPA OG Mugshots';
    $block['content'] = $wanted . $convicted;         
    break;

  default: 
    // Throw an error
    break;
}

return $block;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the arguments are not getting passed properly

```
function views_embed_view($name, $display_id = 'default') {
  $args = func_get_args();
  array_shift($args); // remove $name
  if (count($args)) {
    array_shift($args); // remove $display_id
  }

  $view = views_get_view($name);
  if (!$view || !$view->access($display_id)) {
    return;
  }

  return $view->preview($display_id, $args);
}
```

So you want `$wanted = views_embed_view($viewName, $display_id1, $args[0], $args[1], $args[etc]);`

Also from the [Creator of Views](http://groups.drupal.org/node/17397#comment-59414)

> You either want:
>
> views_embed_view('viewname', 'page_1', 1, 2, 3)
>
> or
>
> views_embed_view('viewname', 'page_1', '1+2+3')
>
> depending on if you have a single argument expecting multiple nids or
>   multiple arguments each expecting a single nid.

Comment: Thank you, worked as soon as I changed my statement to use $args[0] instead of $args.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like instead of rendering the views programmatically you could also leverage the Views "Attachment" display .  The allows you to attach a view to another display, in other words render one view after another.  The "block_1" display of the view you posted above would be the main view displayed as a block, and then you would change the "block_2" display to an attachment and configure the settings similar to the image below.

[image]

This would eliminate the need to create custom code to display both views in a block.

Comment: I've already tried this, it nests the attachment within the first block. I need them side by side in the code.

Comment: Understood.  I would assume you could display them side-by-side by overriding the view's template or writing some CSS.  My design skills are non-existent, though, so take it with a huge grain of salt.