# How to embed a views page and views block in a page?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I want to show two views in a single page. I have created a view page and I have one view block. So how can I attach these two views. I followed this below url, but i didn't get the attchment option in my view editing page.
[How to embed two views into a block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7316/how-to-embed-two-views-into-a-block)

Comment: You need to create an attachment view instead of a block, and in that attachment view you then select the page and position to attach to. [Working with Drupal views attachments](https://www.reinisfischer.com/drupal-developer/working-drupal-views-attachments)

Comment: @J.Reynolds please post that as an answer.

Comment: If your views 2nd display is block, you can simply navigate to "**Admin => Structure => Blocks**", search for that block and [place](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/block) the block on your views page by clicking on "**configure**" link next to it.

Comment: @J.Reynolds Thank you for your quick response. That attachment settings are overriding the pages configuration. How can i make them stick to attachment only.

Comment: When you alter a setting (field, pager etc) on any additional view there will be a listbox on the dialog box that says something like: Apply to All View, Apply to this block/attachment etc only. You need to set it to 'This attachment only'. You can also choose to reset it to the default if you made a mistake.